# What is 'valid?' in RSpec? Where can I look at it?

Tags: ruby, validation, rspec

I've attempted to create a model, which needs to pass a series of validation tests in RSpec. However, I constantly get the error

```
expected #<Surveyor::Answer:0x0055db58e29260 @question=#<Double Surveyor::Question>, @value=5> to respond to `valid?`
```

My understanding ([from here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/valid%3F)) was that 'valid?' checks that no errors were added to the model. I can't find any errors, however the message above persists.

This is my model

```
module Surveyor
  class Answer
    attr_accessor :question, :value

    def initialize(params)
      @question = params.fetch(:question)
      @value = params.fetch(:value)
    end
  end
end
```

And the class Question

```
module Surveyor
  class Question
    attr_accessor :title, :type

    def initialize(params)
      @title = params.fetch(:title, nil)
      @type = params.fetch(:type)
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the test I am attempting to pass

```
RSpec.describe Surveyor::Answer, '03: Answer validations' do

  let(:question) { double(Surveyor::Question, type: 'rating') }

  context "question validation" do
    context "when the answer has a question" do
      subject { described_class.new(question: question, value: 5) }
        it { should be_valid }
    end
  end
```

Is my understanding of 'valid?' correct? Am I able to look at 'valid?' and perhaps see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the code that produced the error you’d better ask a fortuneteller.

Comment: You are mocking nonexisting class `Surveyor::Question`, while the exiting class is named `Surveyor::Answer`.

Comment: I have a class named Question. I've added it to the question.

Comment: Re-read the error: _"expected #<Surveyor::Answer ...> to respond to `valid?`"_ It doesn't say that your answer is invalid, it says that it is missing a `valid?` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec doesn't actually have a matcher called `be_valid`, instead it has some dynamic [predicate matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-6/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers):

> For any predicate method, RSpec gives you a corresponding matcher. Simply prefix the
>   method with `be_` and remove the question mark. Examples:
>
> ```
> expect(7).not_to be_zero       # calls 7.zero?
> expect([]).to be_empty         # calls [].empty?
> expect(x).to be_multiple_of(3) # calls x.multiple_of?(3)
> ```

so by calling `it { should be_valid }`, your subject has to respond to a `valid?` method. If you're testing an `ActiveRecord` model, those have a `valid?` method, but your model does not. So, if you want to test that your `Answer` is valid, you need to decide "what is a valid answer?" and write a method that checks for those conditions. If you want an API similar to Rails model, you might be interested in using [`ActiveModel::Validations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html)